# Changing Formula Range with Another Variable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to adjust how much of a data my formula looks at depending on another variable.

An example would be having 20 years worth of returns `=IRR(A2:A22)`

I'd like to add a variable that you change depending on how many years you would want to look at. Lets say we only wanted to look at the first 10 years how would I get my formula to automatically find the data for `=IRR(A2:A12)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that the year "variable" is in cell A1. It could be any cell, but for this example, A1:

```
=IRR($A$2:INDEX($A:$A,$A$1+2))
```

Notice that $A$1 is in the formula. You change that to your year variable.

Comment: Perfect! It totally works, you really are my Excel Hero.